# Not sure what this is - bag 2, whites, purples, light blues

Tags: set-identification

I got this at the thrift store and have no instructions. Does anyone know what it is?

[image: bag 2, whites, purples, light blues]

Answer (score 3):

[41332-1 Emma's Art Stand](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=41332-1)

Based on

- White Plate, Modified 2 x 2 x 2/3 with 2 Studs on Side
- Medium Lavender Plate, Round Corner 2 x 6 Double
- White Plate 2 x 2 Corner

That yields 3 sets, only 1 of which is a Friends set, and it's one that has that mini-doll in it.

[image: 41332-1 Emma's Art Stand]

Comment: ...but that set doesn't cover all the parts seen. The 8x8 tan plate, 1x3x1 and 1x2x3 white slopes, and other parts from the bag at the top of the photograph are probably from different set(s).

Comment: Yup; trying to ID a set from an unclear photo of a loose collection of parts in an open bag seems like a fool's errand. I concentrated on the do-able task of identifying the sealed bag.

Comment: I wouldn't bet money on that being an 8x8 plate in tan - I can not be at all certain just how big it really is.